# Retrieve the latest entry to my Basic Announce Database

Tags: php, mysql

Some may know my script Basic Announce, I am trying to get the latest news entry that has been sent through so only the last know entry is called up.

In this code block is the news caller that I originally created but this decides to call all of the entries but thats for the Admin to see, but I need the last entry to be called in this file: news.php

```
<?php

// Connects to your Database

mysql_connect("$server","$usr","$pswd") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcements")

or die(mysql_error());



while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))

{

Print "<tr>";

Print "<th>Announcement:</th><td>".$info['Announcement'] . "</td> ";

Print "<br>";

Print "<th>Submitted By:</th> <td>".$info['Submitted'] . "</td> ";

}

;

?>
```

How would I go about select the last know entry I also include my database tables sql code.

Here is the Basic Announce.sql code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `announcements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Announcement` text NOT NULL,
  `Submitted` text NOT NULL,
  `Date_time` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Is it possible to pull the last record using my Primary Key "id"?

Any help on this troubling matter would be greatly appreciated as I am still learn PHP via self-taught and inspiration.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order it by the `id` descending:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcements ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

I also added `LIMIT 1` because you only want to retrieve the first row in the set. Given you only want a single row, you don't need the while loop, just make a single call to fetch:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcements ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

if($data && mysql_num_rows($data) == 1) // check for success and a row found
{
    $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<th>Announcement:</th><td>".$info['Announcement'] . "</td> ";
    Print "<br>";
    Print "<th>Submitted By:</th> <td>".$info['Submitted'] . "</td> ";
}
else
{
    // no rows or an error occurred
}
```

Side notes:

- The `mysql_*` library is deprecated. For new code you should consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi.
- `.. or die(mysql_error())` should be avoided. A better option is `trigger_error(mysql_error())`.

Comment: Thank you Mrcode I am using your answer is looking nice on my script many thanks :)

Comment: MrCode I am truly grateful for your answer it has worked perfectly after an entire recode of the insertion of the data it works nicely in the current test state the next step is to see how how this affects a persons website was looking at it to get it to plain text which might be the right path but nonetheless Version 4.2 should be out soon.

Answer (score 0):

try out this.

```
SELECT Top 1 * FROM announcements order by id desc
```